# Can getEventType() return customized string?

Tags: javafx-8

in java.awt.eventActionEvent
I can put a string to ActionEvent by calling constructor:

```java
public class MyEvent extends ActionEvent {
    public MyEvent(Object source, String myActionName){
        super(source, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, action);
    }
}
```

and listener can get the string by using getEventType():

```java
@override
public void handle(Event e){
    String myActionName = e.getEventType().toString();
}
```

How to achieve this with javafx.event.ActionEvent ?

Can I make method getEvnetType() to return customized string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to emit and handle custom events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416758/how-to-emit-and-handle-custom-events)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But I create an class

    static class MyEvent extends ActionEvent{
        static final EventType<MyEvent> ACTION = new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "PLASMA");
    }
    MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
    System.out.println(event.getEventType().toString());

the result is always “ACTION”, not my custom String: "PLASMA".

does this mean I can’t achieve the result as java.awt.eventActionEvent?

Comment: Ugh, that code is way beyond readable.. but from I can read, it seems you have not called the super constructor of Event where you should pass your custom `EventType`.

Comment: Thanks for such quick answer!! It works  if change code in:  <br/>
*1.* extends Event rather than ActionEvent
    2. call super(PLASMA) in constructor.

Comment: If I want to use javafx.event.ActionEvent rather than Event, is it correct to put the customeized string into static field ACTION?  
I tried assign the string to ACTION in the beginning of the class, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `ActionEvent` has no public constructor where you can pass a custom `EventType`. So you can not customize the event type of the `ActionEvent`.