# How to define Event for Custom Control to be used on a Controller in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a custom control in which i want to define an event which will be implemented in a controller which uses my control

The actual scenario goes as.
I have created a custom control which defines a project. I have to show all project on a scene (separate fxml) using my control. When user clicks on a control then a form should be displayed showing all information about the projects.

As of now i'm saving a reference of form's fxml's parent node on a static variable and setting all textbox of the form from my control's controller.

I want to make it flexible so that i can handle the click event of my control on the form's controller itself.

Can anyone help on this?
Kindly revert if you need more explanation.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416758/how-to-emit-and-handle-custom-events/27420429#27420429