# Custom JavaFX events

Tags: java, events, javafx, listener

I have a custom event listener:

```
public interface IMyCustomListener {

  public void onEvent1(int param0);

  public void onEvent2(String param0);
}
```

now I would fire events with javafx events pattern (Event, EventTarget, EventHandler...), how can I do this?

Comment: Just implement an adapter. But why even bother defining your own interface when you can just use JavaFX's?

Comment: A similar question already has been discussed: [How to emit and handle custom events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416758/how-to-emit-and-handle-custom-events)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. JavaFX uses `javafx.event.Event`s or subtypes, so `String` or even primitive `int` can't be passed.

You could however create a custom subtype of `Event` and add the parameters to this class.

Similarly only classes implementing `javafx.event.EventHandler` can be registered as event handlers.

You could create a event handler class that delegates to your methods though:

```
public abstract class CustomEvent extends Event {

    public static final EventType<CustomEvent> CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE = new EventType(ANY);

    public CustomEvent(EventType<? extends Event> eventType) {
        super(eventType);
    }

    public abstract void invokeHandler(MyCustomEventHandler handler);

}
```

```
public class CustomEvent1 extends CustomEvent {

    public static final EventType<CustomEvent> CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE_1 = new EventType(CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, "CustomEvent1");

    private final int param;

    public CustomEvent1(int param) {
        super(CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE_1);
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeHandler(MyCustomEventHandler handler) {
        handler.onEvent1(param);
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomEvent2 extends CustomEvent {

    public static final EventType<CustomEvent> CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE_2 = new EventType(CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, "CustomEvent2");

    private final String param;

    public CustomEvent2(String param) {
        super(CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE_2);
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeHandler(MyCustomEventHandler handler) {
        handler.onEvent2(param);
    }

}
```

```
public abstract class MyCustomEventHandler implements EventHandler<CustomEvent> {

    public abstract void onEvent1(int param0);

    public abstract void onEvent2(String param0);

    @Override
    public void handle(CustomEvent event) {
        event.invokeHandler(this);
    }
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
Button btn = new Button("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    btn.fireEvent(new CustomEvent1(42));
    btn.fireEvent(new CustomEvent2("Hello World"));
});

btn.addEventHandler(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, new MyCustomEventHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onEvent1(int param0) {
        System.out.println("integer parameter: " + param0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent2(String param0) {
        System.out.println("string parameter: "+param0);
    }
});
```