# How can i make custom event with property?

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

How can I make custom event and custom property 
with access to it from SceneBuilder/FXML?
[Should be available like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxyJ.png)

this source gives the answer but only partially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416758/how-to-emit-and-handle-custom-events)

I need something like:

**MyFragment.fxml**

```
<SplitPane ......>
    <fx:script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            if(MyCustomControl.state){
                id0.setText('1111111')
            } else {
                id0.setText('2222222')
            }
        }
    </fx:script>
                           //How create this property? 
   <Label fx:id="id0" />   //           |              
                           //           V              
   <MyCustomControl        onMyCustomEvent="myFunction()"/>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly in order to get help, thanks

Comment: @Dev It's not a mistake, I can not give code because I ask what code I need to write

Comment: Have you added a `onMyCustomEvent` property of type `EventHandler<T>` (arbitrary type `T` within constraints) to your `MyCustomControl` class)?

Comment: @fabian No) The question is about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Kotlin:**

```
val MY_CUSTOM_EVENT =
    EventType<Event>(Event.ANY, "MY_CUSTOM_EVENT" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
var onOnlineClick = object : SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<Event>>() {
    override fun getBean(): Any {
        return this
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "onMyCustomEvent"
    }

    override fun invalidated() {
        setEventHandler(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT, get())
    }
}

fun onMyCustomEvent(): ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<Event>> {
    return onMyCustomEvent
}

fun setOnMyCustomEvent(value: EventHandler<Event>) {
    onMyCustomEvent.set(value)
}

fun getOnMyCustomEvent(): EventHandler<Event> {
    return onMyCustomEvent.get()
}
```

**Somewhere property**

```
fun myProperty(): BooleanProperty {
    return myCustomProperty ?: run {
        myCustomProperty = object : SimpleBooleanProperty(false) {
            override fun invalidated() {
                fireEvent(Event(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT)) // <---this
            }

            override fun getBean(): Any {
                return this
            }

            override fun getName(): String {
                return "myProperty"
            }
        }
        return myCustomProperty as SimpleBooleanProperty
    }
}
```